# Appropriate programming design questions

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

I have a few questions on good programming design. I'm going to first describe the project I'm building so you are better equipped to help me out.

I am coding a Remote Assistance Tool similar to TeamViewer, Microsoft Remote Desktop, CrossLoop. It will incorporate concepts like UDP networking (using [Lidgren](http://code.google.com/p/lidgren-network-gen3/) networking library), NAT traversal (since many computers are invisible behind routers nowadays), Mirror Drivers (using DFMirage's Mirror Driver (http://www.demoforge.com/dfmirage.htm) for realtime screen grabbing on the remote computer).

That being said, this program has a *concept* of being a client-server architecture, but I made only one program with both the functionality of client *and* server. That way, when the user runs my program, they can switch between giving assistance and receiving assistance without having to download a separate client or server module.

I have a Windows Form that allows the user to choose between giving assistance and receiving assistance. I have another Windows Form for a file explorer module. I have another Windows Form for a chat module. I have another Windows Form form for a registry editor module. I have another Windows Form for the live control module. So I've got a Form for each module, which raises the first question:

**1. Should I process module-specific commands inside the code of the respective Windows Form?** Meaning, let's say I get a command with some data that enumerates the remote user's files for a specific directory. Obviously, I would have to update this on the File Explorer Windows Form and add the entries to the ListView. Should I be processing this code inside the Windows Form though? Or should I be handling this in another class (although I have to eventually pass the data to the Form to draw, of course). Or is it like a hybrid in which I process most of the data in another class and pass the final result to the Form to draw?

So I've got like 5-6 forms, one for each module. The user starts up my program, enters the remote machine's ID (not IP, ID, because we are registering with an intermediary server to enable NAT traversal), their password, and connects. Now let's suppose the connection is successful. Then the user is presented with a form with all the different modules. So he can open up a File Explorer, or he can mess with the Registry Editor, or he can choose to Chat with his buddy. So now the program is sort of idle, just waiting for the user to do something. If the user opens up Live Control, then the program will be spending most of it's time receiving packets from the remote machine and drawing them to the form to provide a 'live' view.

**2.** Second design question. A spin off question #1. **How would I pass module-specific commands to their respective Windows Forms?** What I mean is, I have a class like "NetworkHandler.cs" that checks for messages from the remote machine. NetworkHandler.cs is a static class globally accessible. So let's say I get a command that enumerates the remote user's files for a specific directory. *How* would I "*give*" that command to the File Explorer Form. I was thinking of making an OnCommandReceivedEvent inside NetworkHandler, and having each form register to that event. When the NetworkHandler received a command, it would raise the event, all forms would check it to see if it was relevant, and the appropriate form would take action. Is this an appropriate/the best solution available?

**3. The networking library I'm using, Lidgren, provides two options for checking networking messages.** One can either poll ReadMessage() to return null or a message, or one can use an AutoResetEvent OnMessageReceived (I'm guessing this is like an event). Which one is more appropriate?

Comment: Edward, please don't put tags into the title. That's what tags are for.

Answer (score 1):

1. Put as little code as possible in the form. You should create a seperate class/set of classes to handle this and make the form use them to draw.
2. An event seems like a good idea. I wouldn't let the form subscribe, but have another class do the processing and just pass the processed data to the form (through another event).
3. I would use the event, because it probably checks async, which is what you want. You do not want to lock the form while waiting on messages.

Comment: Thanks for reading my insanely long post and inputting your expertise!